# Crystal Reports Formula for Extracting a Last Name

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I am working on Crystal Reports 2020
I have a field that is exporting as a full name (Mary J. Jones, for instance). Sometimes it is only First and Last Name (Mary Jones). I need a formula to extract ONLY the last name (Jones). The only thing separating the names is a space, so I need the word after the final space.
Thank you in advance.

I have tried a bunch of different formulas but they are not returning what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
Right({name}, Len({name}) - InStrRev({name}, " "));
```

Comment: OP should be aware there are flaws in this type of process for extracting the name.  If the name include a middle name or middle initial, the first space will be between the first name and middle name/initial, so the middle name/initial will be included in the string extract.  And if you adjust to use the string that follows the last space to get around this complication, then you run into another issue with any last names that include a space such as "Mc Cann".

Comment: The solution I provided above uses the location of the LAST space -- not the FIRST space.  So middle name or initials pose no problem.

Comment: I was commenting on the general process rather than your formula.  OP seems to be a bit inexperienced so I wanted to be sure they were aware of the nuances of this type of string extraction for names.  I should have made that more clear in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you.Yes, running into the middle initial was an issue with every other formula I was trying. This one solved it.

I haven't dealt with Crystal reports for almost a decade. Things like this didn't used to trip me up. I'm essentially starting from scratch as I seem to have forgotten everything I knew.

Thank you.